# Carry out a set task for each column with data in it

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range

I would like to use this match function I developed for each entire column with data in it. So currently it works perfectly when I specify

```html
Sub CompareAndMove()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Long, iL As Long, var As Variant
        
    iL = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To iL
        Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
        Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C")
                
       
       var = Application.Match(rng1.Value, rng2, 1)
     
       If Not IsError(Application.Match(rng1.Value, rng2, 0)) Then
       bln = True
       
       If bln = True Then
                    
                    rng1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                    rng1.Copy
                    rng1.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
                    
                    
        End If
        Set rng1 = Nothing
        Set rng2 = Nothing
        End If
        
    Next i

End Sub
```

However I am now trying to skim through all columns with data until it is complete, I am struggling to define the column by using the below script. Any suggestions?

```html
Sub CompareAndMove()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Long, iL As Long, var As Variant, j As Long, jL As Long
        
    iL = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    jL = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
        
    For j = 3 To jL
    
    For i = 2 To iL
        Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
        Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("j:j")
                
       
       var = Application.Match(rng1.Value, rng2, 1)
     
       If Not IsError(Application.Match(rng1.Value, rng2, 0)) Then
       bln = True
       
       If bln = True Then
                    
                    rng1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                    rng1.Copy
                    rng1.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
                    
                    
        End If
        Set rng1 = Nothing
        Set rng2 = Nothing
        End If
        
    Next i
    
'copy column B to another sheet, clear column B so it can start on new column

Next j


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("j:j")
```

should probably be

```
Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(j)
```

or

```
Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(j & ":" & j)
```

Reworked:

```
Sub CompareAndMove()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Long, iL As Long
    Dim var As Variant, j As Long, jL As Long, bln As Variant
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
    iL = sht.Range("A" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    jL = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column

    For j = 3 To jL
        'only need to set this when you swap columns...
        Set rng2 = sht.Range("j:j")

        For i = 2 To iL

           Set rng1 = sht.Range("A" & i)

           var = Application.Match(rng1.Value, rng2, 1) 'why this?

           If Not IsError(Application.Match(rng1.Value, rng2, 0)) Then
                bln = True
                With rng1
                    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                    .Copy .Offset(0, 1)
                End With
           End If

        Next i

    Next j
    'no need to set ranges to Nothing...

End Sub
```